# Exception Mapper not getting invoked in JAX-RS jerey

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jax-rs

I am trying to configure an ExceptionMapper that will catch all the 404 related exception in my application. This is the first time I am trying t play around with this ExceptionMapper, hence facing lots of issue, might be missing something silly :(

Below is what I did in the **ExceptionMapper** class:

```
public class ClassNotFoundMapper implements ExceptionMapper<NotFoundException> {

@Override
public Response toResponse(NotFoundException ex) {
    return Response.status(404).entity(ex.getMessage()).type("text/plain").build();
}
```

}

In **web.xml** I added this entry:

```
<init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>
            com.service.rest;
            com.service.exception
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
```

In the **service** I did this:

```
@GET
@Path("{param}")
public Response getName(@PathParam("param") String msg, @HeaderParam("name") String headerName) {

    //SOME CODE HERE AND THEN CONDITIONALLY RETURN THE EXCEPTION
    return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).entity("NOT FOUND").build(); 
}
```

The exception present in the ExceptionMapper is not getting invoked.

Please let me know what am I missing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're missing the `@Provider` annotation on your `ClassNotFoundMapper`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It works for 404 exception thrown when the URL triggered for the service is incorrect. But again, if I throw an exception from my application code (as shown in the above post like this): `return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).entity("NOT FOUND").build(); ` then the `ExceptionMapper` it is not getting invoked. Any specific reasons for this? Please let me know about it.

Comment: Try throwing a `NotFoundException` instead of constructing a `Response`. `ExceptionMapper`s are for uncaught Java exceptions rather than for `Response`s with non-200 statuses.